# how to get the output of the console application in eclipse using java in the specified path file?

Tags: java

i mapped a xxxx_en_US.properties and excelsheet of keys and values..
The output of those mapped keyvalues are shown in eclipse as console application.

Is that possible ,to move those mapped output values to the given path file in ecplise?

can anyone guide me for this?

Comment: You want to write on file what you seen in console...yes?

Comment: yes.. sir, u are correct..

Answer (score 1):

Go to `Run -> Run Configuration -> Common`,

In standard Input and Output, you can give the file as well.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a logger.  Logging is a facility to redirect any output in the Java Console to a trace file. Check these:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/deployment/deployment-guide/tracing_logging.html

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/logging/package-summary.html

http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/